# My blogger site is disabled and marked as spam. How can I restore my blog?

Tags: seo, google, blogger

My blog url is `banners-bannerbuzz.blogspot.com`

I have already "clicked to Restore", But no reply till now...
When I clicked again this message was displayed:

> Blogger's spam-prevention robots have detected that your blog has
>   characteristics of a spam blog. Since you are an actual person
>   reading this, your blog is probably not a spam blog. Automated spam
>   detection is inherently fuzzy and we sincerely apologise for this false
>   positive.
>
> We received your unlock request on 15 March 2011. On behalf of the
>   robots, we apologise for locking your non-spam blog. Please be patient
>   while we take a look at your blog and verify that it is not spam.

Can anyone suggest what can i do, i want my blog back, because it has a PageRank of 2, and gets 30,000 visits from it.

Comment: Can you access your blogs design, layout ,posts or setting ?

Comment: How many days are require for the recovery?

Answer (score 7):

I went on the cache version of your blog.  It seems like it is low quality and badly written content, with a lot of adverts all over the place, with the actual aim to direct visitors to your main website, bannerbuzz.com.  A lot of the content you have written looks like it's been outsourced and this is reflected in the generally low quality of the posts. An example would be:

> When a car owner decides to design the car with a decal, there would be a reason behind it. The reasons are a galore these days. Each person wants to do this because they find a good reason to do so.  Whatever it might be, the popularity of **Car Decals** [link to your main site] have sky rocketed with the time. A person who sits behind the wheel knows how it feels grabbing the attention!

That's why it got taken down, the blog itself doesn't contribute anything useful to anyone searching for it.  That sentence is a whole load of words without any meat at all in it with the sole aim to get people to click through to your commercial site.  You probably got some bad advice somewhere down the line about how to write it for SEO or where to look to outsource the content.

Run the blog on your own site if you think it has value or via another service.  I like the fact Google is working on removing these sorts of sites.  You might kid yourself into thinking it's a useful blog people read but it doesn't look like it to me.

That might come off as harsh but it's the reality of the situation.

Comment: Thank you so much for give me such wonderful suggestion, bu t i am very happy to got my blogger blog back. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Nishi I didn't suggest anything to you but thanks for the compliment and good luck with your site!

Answer (score 2):

You could set up your site in [Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) and request reconsideration that way. Google recently published a blog post about how they are responding to requests better http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/reconsideration-requests-get-more.html

Comment: Thank you so much for give me such wonderful suggestion, bu t i am very happy to got my blogger blog back. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are various reasons why Google removes blog. In your case they think your blog is spammy and that's why it was removed.

Can you access your blogs design, layout ,posts or setting

If yes, you can export your blog Posts to xml file and create a new blog with better url and you can simple restore all of your posts by Importing the XML file.So you dong need to write all of your posts again.

Comment: Thank you so much for give me such wonderful suggestion, bu t i am very happy to got my blogger blog back. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Uh, "We received your unlock request on **15 March 2011**." It seems like you may have come back to it too late. If you have a Blogger blog disabled like this it's important to stay on the situation until it's restored and not wait around. They'll take a lack of response, including logging in to the account, as a lack of interest in the situation and keep the blog disabled.

On the Blogger anti-spam 'bot it will frequently get a false positive result. One cause I've seen can be caused by cutting and pasting an article into the editor and quickly clicking the submit button or by using an off-line editor to post the article. To avoid this one, after pasting, wait about 30 seconds before submitting and don't use an off-line editor to post the article. Using Javascript in the post text can also set it off so avoid using scripts in your post.

Another common cause is reporting, both real and malicious. This is hard to avoid but as long as you aren't spammy and the reports are false you'll be OK and may even be given an exclusion from having these reports count against you.

Comment: Thank you so much for give me such wonderful suggestion, bu t i am very happy to got my blogger blog back. Thanks a lot